# How to invoke correct version of requireJS multi-version config?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am trying to switch between multiple configuration versions, as described [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#multiversion)

Here my main.js:

```
var config1 = require.config({
    paths: {
        message: 'mocks/mockMessage' // returns "mocked message"
    }
});

var config2 = require.config({
    paths: {
        message: 'mocks/anotherMockMessage' // returns "another mocked message"
    }
});

config1(["require"], function (require) {
    require(['jquery', 'message'], function ($, message) {
        $('#output').html(message);
    }); 
});
```

Although I call config1, the text is set to "another mocked message". Looks like runtime executes first config1 and then config2 which overwrites the "message" configuration.

So how can I define multiple configurations without applying them so I can later call the one I need?

BTW, if I add "context" property to config, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to define your local modules via paths? You could load your modules programatically through the require function to circumvent your name collision in the paths object of your require config.  [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/BvsKKRxMYFk0qaowtmXF?p=preview)

Comment: I know modules can be loaded programmatically, I just want to understand how to achieve it using requireJS multi-version config.